# can I use CSS in servlet coding?

Tags: servlets

Is there a way to use CSS in servlet coding?

Comment: You should really post some code.  It is hard to understand what you mean by "calling a servlet from an HTML page."  Is this JSP?  And what does "CSS instead of the HTML mean"?

Comment: the html page your servlet produces is normal html. It has to link to a css stylesheet in its header in the normal, as every html page does.

Comment: @Raj: your edit doesn't really make the question easier to understand. Please try to explain what you're doing instead of just deleting parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you want to have it relative to the context path you can also write LINK as

```
<LINK REL="StyleSheet" HREF="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/util/CSS/Style.css" TYPE="text/css">
```

Where, /util/CSS is a folder underneath your context path (e.g. /webapp/examples in case of a typical Tomcat set up).

However, you must make sure that the entire path is accurately typed (i.e. is case sensitive).

Hope this additional clarification helps.

Comment: please elaborate more 1) where i need to write that LINK tag? ..is it an extra file or in the servlet program itself ? 2)im using tomcat v8.5 in eclipse oxygen so where to setup the CSS folder in tomcat folder?@amod0017

Answer (score 4):

Yes! there is a way of using css in servlets. This can be achieved by the following way; First create an object of PrintWriter class, `"PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();"` after this step you can use "`out.print("<html><head><style='text/css'>{}</style></head>")";` inside the curly braces you can write the code for IDs or Classes. After or before of `"out.print()"` you can write your servlet code. Do not forget to close `<html>` and other tags.

Comment: I've tried but no displaying proper design and displaying only style css code in output

Answer (score 0):

CSS can be used in a Servlet by including styles directly in generated HTML:

```
try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
  out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
  out.println("<html>");
  out.println("<head>");
  out.println("<meta charset=\"utf-8\">");  // escape the quote marks
  out.println("<title>Glassfish HTML Testing</title>");
  out.println("<style>");     // start style
  // enclose style attributes withing the <style> </style> elements
  out.println("h1 {");        // note leading brace
  out.println("color:blue;");
  out.println("background-color:yellow;");
  out.println("border: 1px solid black;");
  out.println("}");          // note trailing brace for h1 style
  // add styles for other elements here using similar structure
  // note that separate lines are used for clarity -
  // all of the above could be one println
  out.println("</style>");  // terminate style
  out.println("</head>");
  out.println("<body>");
  out.println("<h1>Servlet located at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
  out.println("</body>");
  out.println("</html>");
}  // end of try-with-resources block
```

The above code should be in the processRequest method of the Servlet (assuming the generated page is appropriate for GET and POST requests)